# Replace a String inside a file using java

Tags: java, file

I have a TXT file in which I'd like to change this String

`<!DOCTYPE Publisher
PUBLIC "-//Springer-Verlag//DTD A++ V2.4//EN" "http://devel.springer.de/A++/V2.4/DTD/A++V2.4.dtd">`

into this one `<!DOCTYPE Publisher>` using Java.

I wrote the following function but it seems not to be working.

```
public void replace() {

try {
    File file = new File("/home/zakaria/Bureau/PhD/test2/file.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = "", oldtext = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       oldtext += line + "\n";
    }
    reader.close();
    String newtext = oldtext
      .replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE Publisher\nPUBLIC \"-//Springer-Verlag//DTD A++ V2.4//EN\" \"http://devel.springer.de/A++/V2.4/DTD/A++V2.4.dtd\">", 
      "<!DOCTYPE Publisher>");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/home/zakaria/Bureau/PhD/test2/file.txt");
    writer.write(newtext);
    writer.close();

  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what is happening when you say - "No Working"??

Comment: any error or sumthing ?

Comment: You should put the modified content in _another file_ and only then rename to the original. What do you think will happen if the write fails?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 no errors at all, I tried with a simple word and it was working fine

Comment: oldText has newlines in it but the first parameter to replaceAll does not.

Comment: @fge I put the result in a different file and still no result

Comment: @JohnnyMopp could you explain more please?

Comment: I was referring to the general process here; so far you have been lucky not to lose anything, but luck will only get you so far

Comment: try replacing `PUBLIC "-//Springer-Verlag//DTD A++ V2.4//EN" "http://devel.springer.de/A++/V2.4/DTD/A++V2.4.dtd"1 only instead of DOCTYPE.

Comment: @A5l-lE5 I already tried that, still the same result!

Comment: String.replaceAll() takes a regex as argument, not a literal String. Use replace() instead. And make sure your file doesn't use \r\n to separate lines. Try replacing only the beginning, then a larger string, then an even larger, until you find where the problem is in your large original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple code:

```
public static void replace() {

    try {
        File file = new File("resources/abc.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        boolean found = false;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().startsWith("<!DOCTYPE Publisher")) {
                found = true;
            }
            if (line.trim().endsWith("A++V2.4.dtd\">")) {
                oldtext += "<!DOCTYPE Publisher>";
                found = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (found) {
                continue;
            }
            oldtext += line + "\n";
        }
        reader.close();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("resources/file.txt");
        writer.write(oldtext);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fortunate to start with that it didn't change anything at all.

Otherwise you'd have lost your original file...

**Never modify a file in place!!**

Create a temporary file where you write the modified content, and only then rename to your original file.

Also, the string you want to replace is pretty complicated, and you don't want to use `.replace()` since this will replace all occurrences.

Do like this:

```
final String quoted 
    = Pattern.quote("<!DOCTYPE Publisher\nPUBLIC \"-//Springer-Verlag//DTD A++ V2.4//EN\" \"http://devel.springer.de/A++/V2.4/DTD/A++V2.4.dtd\">");
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(quoted);

final Path victim = Paths.get("/home/zakaria/Bureau/PhD/test2/file.txt");
final Path tmpfile = Files.createTempFile("tmp", "foo");

final byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(victim);
final String s = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final String replacement = pattern.matcher(s).replaceFirst("<!DOCTYPE Publisher>");

try (
    final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(tmpfile);
) {
    out.write(replacement.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    out.flush();
}
Files.move(tmpfile, victim);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want to eliminate is on the second and subsequent lines, as in your demo-input

```
<!DOCTYPE Publisher
PUBLIC "-//Springer-Verlag//DTD A++ V2.4//EN"     
"http://devel.springer.de/A++/V2.4/DTD/A++V2.4.dtd">
```

and no lines between the first and last in the tag contain a closing `>`, then you can do the following:

```
while(more lines to process)
   if "<!DOCTYPE Publisher" is not found
      read line and output it
   else
      //This is the first line in a <!DOCTYPE tag
      read the line and output it, appending '>' to the end
      while the next line does NOT end with a '>'
         discard it (don't output it)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regexp:

```
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(
       "<!DOCTYPE Publisher\nPUBLIC \"-\\/\\/Springer-Verlag\\/\\/DTD A[+][+] V2[.]4\\/\\/EN\"[ ]\"http:\\/\\/devel[.]springer[.]de\\/A[+][+]\\/V2[.]4\\/DTD\\/A[+][+]V2[.]4[.]dtd\">", "<!DOCTYPE Publisher>");
```

The only changes are escaping forward slashes and putting dots and plus signs between square brackets.